# reading files into memory while walking directory structure with nio

Tags: java, io, nio

How can I read files into memory while walking a directory tree using Java NIO?

The following code is my first attempt:

```
String dirStart = "/start/directory/";

Path root = Paths.get(dirStart);
Files.walkFileTree(root.toAbsolutePath().normalize(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(file);
    String[] dirs = file.toString().split("/");
    String var1 = dirs[2];String var2 = dirs[3];String var3 = dirs[4];
    System.out.println("var1 is: "+var1);
    System.out.println("var2 is: "+var2);
    System.out.println("var3 is: "+var3);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(file);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        System.out.println("Reading Line: " + bufferedReader.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {bufferedReader.close();}
        catch (IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace();}
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

But the following line is throwing a null pointer error:

```
try {bufferedReader.close();}
```

Perhaps the problem might be that the code above is mixing `java.nio` with `java.io`, but how can I fix it?

**ANSWER:**

As per `SotiriosDelimanolis`'s suggestion, I tried nesting `try-with-resources` statements, and got the following code, which solves this problem and answers this question:

```
Path root = Paths.get(dirStart);
Files.walkFileTree(root.toAbsolutePath().normalize(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        try(InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(file);BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))){
            System.out.println("Reading Line: " + bufferedReader.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `try-with-resources`?

Comment: Presumably something else in your code is throwing an exception before you can initialize `bufferedReader`. Since your code doesn't attempt to `catch` such an exception, the `finally` executes before the exception is thrown to the caller. Use `try-with-resources`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

You can nest declarations.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I used your suggestion to derive some code that works.  Thank you.  I posted it at the end of my OP above.  If you feel like writing it up as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ah, that's fine. You can write up an answer for yourself. Note that if you get an exception, you might want to return a different `FileVisitResult`.